# in-app Screenshot and attach to email IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, screenshot

I would like to know the code to take a screenshot and bring up the email window and attach the screenshot to the email by just pressing one button within the app. So far i have written the code to bring up the email window with the push of a button i would like the same button to take and attach the screenshot. If you can point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender {
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
    NSString *messageBody = @"CHECK OUT MY NEW SCORE!";
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"example@gmail.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

MFMailComposeViewController class has this function.

```
-(void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename
```

this will get the screen shot

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.window.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
 [self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

And then do this in your code

```
[mc addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myscreenshot.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Sendgrid Evangelist here, the code below uses iOS 7 functionality to take a screenshot and our iOS sdk to email the image.

```
- (UIImage *)screenshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

- (IBAction)sendScreenshot:(id)sender {
    UIImage *screen = [self screenshot];
    sendgrid *msg = [sendgrid user:@"username" andPass:@"password"];

    msg.to = @"foo@bar.com";
    msg.subject = @"screenshot";
    msg.from = @"bar@foo.com";
    msg.text = @"screenshot";
    msg.html = @"<h1>screenshot</h1>";

    [msg attachImage:screen];
    [msg sendWithWeb];
}
```